# NGINX redirecting the wrong subdomains

Tags: nginx, web-server, https

I have setup my NGINX to only accept HTTPS traffic on port 443 and I want to redirect all non-HTTPS traffic from port 80 to HTTPS.

I also have multiple subdomains I want to manage independently.

I'm going to post an example from my configuration but will omit the boring stuff.

The main website that regular user should be able to browse:

```
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name www.myserver.com;

    root /var/www/www.myserver.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

One of the subdomains:

```
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name subdomain.myserver.com;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8500;
    }
}
```

And now I want to redirect traffic from port 80 to HTTPS:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name subdomain.myserver.com;

    return 301 https://subdomain.myserver.com$request_uri;
}
```

The Problem: **ALL** subdomains are automatically being redirected to "https://subdomain.myserver.com", even if they do not match the server name specified in the redirect block.

"http://www.myserver.com" (for which there is no config block) will get redirected to "https://subdomain.myserver.com" even though it doesn't match the server_name

Comment: The problem is nginx is overly helpful. If you point a domain internally or externally at nginx it will answer. If you don't want it to decide on its own which config block to apply you need to use `default_server` take a look here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: Do you have HSTS headers sent on the main domain?

Comment: If you want all sites to be redirected correctly `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` to have `http://www.myserver.com` redirect to `https://www.myserver.com`.  
  
If not you need to have a server block with `listen 80 default_server;` and return an error with `return 418;` or something to act as a catch all for nginx to server something or it will fail to the wrong server block

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Catch All" server block, [as documented](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/#a-default-catch-all-server-block):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Another possible cause for the "redirects" are [HSTS heades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). Once a client has seen HSTS headers with `includeSubDomains` set on the main domain, it will also try to access it's subdomains directly with HTTPS, without trying HTTP first.

Comment: That did not help for me. Because I have the same problem as him. I'll try to access my homepage with the rootdomain and the subdomain just overrides everything. I call mydomain.com but subdomain.mydomain.com is called. Only when I set the homepage as second subdomain it works...

Answer (score 0):

According to the link https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html given in Drifter104 comment, the first server definition encountered in the config for specific port assumed default, that's why all subdomains redirected to the first server definition. Try creating config `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default_server.conf` with the following content:

```
server {
    listen  80     default_server;
    server_name default.myserver.com;
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name default.myserver.com;
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

After restarting nginx, all the domains that is not explicitly listed in config will show 404 error.